# Jupyter notebook: how to run python shell command on current kernel?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to run a simple

`!python script.py`

command within a Jupyter notebook running on a custom kernel (virtual environment) where I installed a number of modules. When I run the above command, I am getting some errors related to missing modules, meaning it is not running that code on the same virtual environment as the jupyter notebook.

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Activate the virtual environment as part of the command line? Maybe create a simple wrapper shell script which activates the env and runs your code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will give that a try but I'm currently having problems in running `conda activate my_env`, getting `conda: command not found`

Answer (score 0):

First activate the virtual env then start your notebook.Then it will have your activated virtual env packages

```
source stackpy/bin/activate

sudo jupyter notebook --allow-root
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The jupyterlab environment is hosted on an online server and unfortunately I don't have that kind of access. So this solution is not viable for me.